# Put the hash in the query part of the filename rather than including it is file

Tags: javascript, angular, bundle

when setting:

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
                       ...
                       "outputHashing": "all",
                       ...
         }
}
```

I get something like: styles.1e072cee432cd678e43c.css

Is there a way to get this result: styles.css?1e072cee432cd678e43c ?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the correct build? Try clearing the build directory and running the proper build again to make sure. With outputHashing disabled you shouldn't be getting hash attached to the file.

Comment: Sorry @TotallyNewb I've edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash is calculated based on the contents of each bundle - so it can (but doesn't have to) change on each build. It's calculated by the webpack at build-time, so there's no easy way to pre-calculate it.

If I needed the hash for some reason (i.e. for some CI/CD stuff) I'd probably use an NPM [Post  Script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts) to read the contents of the output directory. So, in your package .json where you have your scripts, you probably have a `build` one. If you add a `postbuild` script, it will be run after the build was run. Or, if you have `build-prod` script you would need `postbuild-prod` respectively, etc.

Concerning the contents of the script - there's no universal answer, as it depends on your build configuration (i.e. which files do you need? style only? others? do you use namedChunks? where will be the files outputted? etc.) and your shell (i.e. it might cmd or powershell on windows machine, or some kind of bash on linux, or something else entirely). For that you're probably better off creating a new question tagged with your shell of choice.